Can clang-format eliminate whitespace within angle bracket of include statement?
Consider this include statement.  Notice the extra space after iostream:
#include <iostream >

msvc will compile this, but gcc does not.  So our Windows devs may not see this failure until our CI process builds with gcc.
Is there a way to get clang-format to remove the extra space within the angle brackets of the include statement?
I've looked through the documentation for things related to includes and spaces, but cannot find anything that removes the space.
SpacesInAngles - This controls spaces in angle brackets for things like templates, but does not change includes.  (We prefer spaces in angles in most of our code).

Perhaps you could add a git-hook that runs clang-tidy on the changes instead? That would result in error: 'iostream ' file not found, did you mean 'iostream'? [clang-diagnostic-error] - other than that, people should learn how to write includes pretty quickly if they get blocked in gate time after time.

Alternative would be for everyone to use Docker or other container solution, such that everyone is compiling in the same environment. Or at least using MinGW on Windows, so that you have a (semi-) common compiler.

If your in an environment where multiple compilers are use build ALL your components for multiple compilers, preferably using a CI/CD pipeline + unit tests and on clang debug builds run those tests with ubsanitizer enabled. The goal of your process should be to catch problems early and that would mena you have C++ developers (not pure windows developer or linux developers, at least not for your reusable libraries)

@Ted, I like the clang-tidy hook idea.  Thank you.  I was hoping there was a clang-format feature that I just couldn't find.

You definitely can't do this with a compiler-agnostic formatting tool because the exact content within angle brackets can matter. The standard says that what exact file is searched for based on the exact string within angle brackets is implementation-defined, and when you look at e.g. GCC preprocessor documentation (section 2.6), you find that even the spaces are used.
On Linux, I can touch "myheader.h " and compile the following with G++ 14 and -I $(pwd):
#include <myheader.h >

int main() {}

Note the trailing spaces in filename (yes, this is possible!) and include directive. Removing either leads to compilation error.
What to do?
I'm assuming here that you want to detect and remove these spaces in all cases, not just when it would lead to a compilation error later. Otherwise you can just take the lazy way, ignore it and deal with compilation errors if they appear - it's not particularly difficult to fix and devs will learn to avoid it if it's a common enough mistake to warrant this attention.
Make a custom pre-commit hook (or CI job etc) where you look for this pattern. A simple pair of extended regexes like ^#include <\s+(.*)>$ and ^#include <(.*)\s+>$ should cover 99% of cases - including block comments and ifdefs. Then you can raise a warning or error with suggested fix.
Of course, this will make your codebase unable to include anything with leading or trailing spaces, which is why code formatters don't offer this option.

.* should probably be [^>]*.  You don't want to error on #include <algorithm> // for std::aggregate< X >  And then you can eliminate the anchors... you don't want to pass #include < iostream > // for std::cout

@BenVoigt Sure, but it leads down a deep rabbit hole like code in strings or inlined in documentation comments... I'd just recommend putting trailing comments of includes on separate lines and ignoring more complex include-looking stuff for the purposes of this check. That leaves indented and (inline)commented includes, which I also glossed over :P but they're easy to handle.
